# decompile third-party shared libraries in solaris

Tags: c, solaris

Is it possible to decompile third-party shared libraries built for solaris into C code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort of.  The short answer is: not really well.

The long answer is to read what REC and other "reverse" compilers do.

Maybe try here REC:

http://www.backerstreet.com/rec/rec.htm

try Rational Rose as well:

http://www.slac.stanford.edu/BFROOT/www/Computing/Environment/Tools/Rose.html

They can create C.  or C++.  Whether you can read it is another story.

Comment: from the program description  it looks like it is more appropiate for executables